# how to find control of static control without for loop

Tags: asp.net, gridview

```
          private void searchgrid()
    {

            GridViewRow HeaderGridRow = new GridViewRow(0, 1, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Normal);
            TableCell HeaderCell = new TableCell();

            HeaderCell.Text = "";
            TextBox abc = new TextBox();
            HeaderCell.Controls.Add(abc);
            HeaderCell.ColumnSpan = 3;
            HeaderGridRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell);

            HeaderCell = new TableCell();
            HeaderCell.Text = "";
            TextBox search = new TextBox();
            search.ID = "search1";
            HeaderCell.Controls.Add(search);
            HeaderCell.ColumnSpan = 3;
            HeaderGridRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell);

            HeaderCell = new TableCell();

            Button btn_chk = new Button();
            btn_chk.Text = "go";
            HeaderCell.Controls.Add(btn_chk);
            HeaderCell.ColumnSpan = 1;
            btn_chk.Click += new EventHandler(btnClick);
            HeaderGridRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell);

            //tbl1.Controls.Add(HeaderGridRow);

            //btn_chk.CommandName = "btn_chk";

            GridView2.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(0, HeaderGridRow);
            //GridView2.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(0, tbl1);


        }
```

i have  a gridview,inside this there is another dynamically created gridview which hAS a textbox.how to find control of this  textbox.by looping i get the values but  i don get the desired output..so i need just one textbox value..please help

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without a loop like this:

```
GridView gv = GridView1.Rows[0].FindControl("GridView2") as GridView; 
TextBox tb = gv.Rows[0].FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox;
string tbValue = tb.Text;
```

You find the nested GridView first and cast it, then you can find the TextBox in the nested GridView.

And you could still always use a loop:

```
    foreach (GridViewRow parentRow in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (parentRow.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            GridView gv = (GridView)parentRow.FindControl("GridView2");
            foreach (GridViewRow childRow in gv.Rows)
            {
                if (childRow.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    TextBox tb = (TextBox)childRow.FindControl("TextBox1");
                    string tbValue = tb.Text;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```